# Naruto fighting game with Hulk and Homer Simpson?

Tags: game-identification

8-bit-looking Naruto fighting game with Hulk and Homer Simpson. Madara is overpowered, and I think Homer's victory speech included "mango". Game name included "mugen" but unsure if officially - played it about 15 years ago.

Which game could it be? This is the exact Hulk:

[image]

Comment: I've asked about this question on [meta] to clarify if this question complies with our game identification policy: [Does the media included in the "Naruto fighting game with Hulk and Homer Simpson?" question comply with our game identification policy?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16197/4797)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It was made with the M.U.G.E.N. game engine, which supports custom game creation - thanks to @Wondercricket for pointing it. Given its nature, that exact game may not exist for download - but it can be recreated.

There doesn't seem a single best way to do so, and some contain viruses - so I'll share what worked cleanly for me:

1. Download [Naruto MUGEN](https://naruto-mugen.en.uptodown.com/windows/download)
2. Download [Homer](https://www.mediafire.com/file/mnf6bq445cjn1wc/RDC_Homer_V0.7.zip/file) -- [Hulk](https://archive.is/ZiDm7) (the sites look sketchy but direct antivirus scan found nothing)

   - Also see [incomplete roster](https://mugen.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Characters), with [SpongeBob & Donald Duck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB8Ma.png)
3. Add Homer & Hulk to `data/` and `chars/` (make sure unzipped files are directly inside the folder, i.e. `Hulk/*` rather than `Hulk/Hulk/*`)
4. Edit `data/select.def` as:

```
RDC_Homer_V0.7, stages/mybg.def, includestage=0
Hulk, stages/mybg.def, includestage=0
AkatsukiMadara299, stages/AkatsukiMadara299.def
```

The launcher is `ultimat naruto mugen screenpack.exe`, and you can watch AIs battle with the `assistir luta` option in-game.

In other news, these two can *sometimes* best Madara

[image]

Comment: Fantastic work! I'm **genuinely impressed** you managed to find out about MUGEN, download it, track down all the resourcepacks, download them, test everything, and write an answer in slightly under 5 hours.

Comment: Is it alright to include those download links? We won't get into trouble for copyright infringement, will we?

Comment: @Nolonar [The license](http://infinitymugenteam.com/infinity.wiki/mediawiki/index.php?title=Mugen_License_Agreement) permits free redistribution, so it seems fine. Also the project is community-maintained with official development [discontinued in 2003](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mugen_(game_engine)), and the whole point _is_ redistribution.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, that's just for M.U.G.E.N. I was thinking more about Naruto, Hulk, Homer, and so on.

Comment: @Nolonar I wouldn't know, but the game's stood for 20 years with these characters, so whatever's being infringed isn't being enforced, similar to [Toontown Rewritten](https://www.toontownrewritten.com/).